# JS working with JSON - Am i using brackets wrong?

Tags: javascript, json, brackets

```
console.log (articles[0].title);
console.log (articles[0].media[0].copyright);
```

->this works!

but all 3 bracket notation below does not! Obvious mistake?? I need to access "media-metadata" and because of special character is need brackets right? Its explained everywhere and seem straighforward but then I have no idea why it is not working.

```
console.log (articles[0].media[0].['media-metadata']);
console.log (articles.[0]['media'][0]);
console.log (['articles'][0]['media'][0]['media-metadata'][0]['url'][2]);
```

thanks for help !

json is copyrighted and complicated, but i checked the hierarchies over and over.

Comment: What are the error messages and where are the problems of understanding them?

Comment: Can you add an example object? Also, try removing the dot after media[0] in the first console.log

Comment: yeah, like "i have problem with my code on some json, but i will not show you this json, try to guess", there are no telepaths here dude...

Comment: Go easy guys, he is obviously new to these things

Comment: i think you just trying to use wrong syntacsis, after dot you are supposed to have name of field, [‘media’] is not name of field, but something else

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

Line 1:

```
console.log (articles[0].media[0].['media-metadata']);
```

The `.['media-metadata']` is wrong, remove the dot such that it becomes

```
console.log (articles[0].media[0]['media-metadata']);
```

You can use *either* dot *or* the brackets to access nested properties, for numerically indexed properties or properties containing some special characters (like `-`) which are not allowed in a property identifier or variable, the bracket notation is mandatory.

Line 2:

```
console.log (articles.[0]['media'][0]);
```

`articles.[0]` is invalid, it should be `articles[0]`:

```
console.log (articles[0]['media'][0]);
```

Again, you have used both a dot and the brackets.

Line 3:

```
console.log (['articles'][0]['media'][0]['media-metadata'][0]['url'][2]);
```

The first part of wrong, instead of beginning with `['articles']` you should use `articles`:

```
console.log (articles[0]['media'][0]['media-metadata'][0]['url'][2]);
```

While your expression is syntactically okay, it does not mean what you want (the first part was an array containing one element which is the text "articles") - you probably want to use the object stored in the variable called `articles`.

Answer (score 1):

The way an object works is like this

```
var obj = {
 foo: bar,
 foo2: [
    bar1, bar2, bar3
 ],
 foo3: {
     prop1: 1,
     prop2: 2,
     prop3: 3
  }
 };
```

We can access its values using either the "." notation or the ["property"] notation but not both, however we can combine them like so:

```
obj.foo === obj["foo"] //true, they are both bar
obj.foo2[2] === obj["foo2"][2] //true, they are both bar3

//I know syntactically this is incorrect but they are all the equivalent
obj.foo3.prop3 === obj["foo3"]["prop3"] === obj.foo3["prop3"] === obj["foo3"].prop3
```